# Parse the following from HTML code?

Tags: c#, regex

How would i parse the following:

```
wr("website-url.com</span>")
```

with regex from HTML code?

Cant seem to figure out how to extract the `website-url.com`

The whole JavaScript that lies within the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">wr("<span>maddog");wr("@");wr("website-url.com</span>")</script>
```

Tried regex like:

```
wr("(.+?)\s*<\/span>")
```

but cant seem to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = <script type="text/javascript">wr("<span>maddog");wr("@");wr("website-url.com</span>")</script>;
string[] b= a.replace("script type="text/javascript">","").replace("</script>","").split(';').ToArray();
string c = b.Last();
string d = c.replace("wr(","").replace("</span","");
```

d is the final result, but you may modify the code to deal with double quote in the string.

Comment: If the html code does never change this may work, but even an extra <space> can make this solution fail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the site you got this javascript doesn't want you to parse its html. It creates dynamic html with a javascript function `wr`. Below is the code to execute this javascript  and parse the resulting code. Hovewer I can not say that this is a simple code to trace

```
public void Test()
{
    //C# object which will be accessed by javascript
    var csharpObj = new MyCSharpObject();

    //Create Javascript object
    Type scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));
    dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
    obj.Language = "Javascript";
    obj.AddObject("csharp", csharpObj);

    //Load Html (your string in question)
    string html = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">wr(""<span>maddog"");wr(""@"");wr(""website-url.com</span>"")</script>";
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    //Create "wr" function
    string script = "function wr(s){csharp.wr(s);}";

    //Get the text of script tag                
    script += doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script").InnerText;

    //Execute script
    obj.Eval(script);

    //Load the string created by javascript execution
    doc.LoadHtml(csharpObj.Output);

    //tada.....
    var eMailAddress = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;

    Console.WriteLine(eMailAddress);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyCSharpObject
{
    public string Output = "";
    public void wr(string s)
    {
        Output += s;
    }
}
```

**--------EDIT--------**

> Im not sure how to write the "Get all the wr(*) strings

Although it seems you want a solution like this, I wouldn't depend on Regex to parse an html

```
public void Test2()
{
    string html = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">wr(""<span>maddog"");wr(""@"");wr(""website-url.com</span>"")</script>";

    var parsedHtml = String.Join("",Regex.Matches(html, @"wr\(\""(.+?)\""\)")
                                            .Cast<Match>()
                                            .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value));

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(parsedHtml);
    var eMailAddress = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is:

- Get all the wr(*) strings with one regex.
- Remove quote marks (")
- Remove `<span>` and `</span>`

Here is a solution in Python.

```
import re

def geturl(text):
    '''
    Get all the wr(*) strings.
    Remove quotes.
    Remove <span> and </span>
    '''
    regex = re.compile(r'wr\(([^)]*)\)')
    match = regex.findall(xx)
    url = ''.join([s.replace('"', '') for s in match])
    url = url.replace('<span>', '').replace('</span>', '')
    return url

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xx = '''<script type="text/javascript">wr("<span>maddog");wr("@");wr("website-url.com</span>")</script>'''
    url = geturl(xx)
    print url
```

Gives `maddog@website-url.com`

Comment: I think there are two problems with this answer **a)** trying to parse html with regex (see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)) **b)** OP wants a c# solution

Comment: How would i write that in C#? :) Im not sure how to write the "Get all the wr(*) strings."

Answer (score -1):

If you're using regular expressions to parse HTML, you are probably doing something the hard way that you could be doing the easy way. In C#, try using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). See also the [definitive question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) on the matter.

Comment: it is javascript within the HTML

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: if it is javascript within HTML, why did you tag it c# regex?